# How to run a NodeJS version for Intel on mac M1?

Tags: node.js, apple-m1, nvm

At first I had problems with running Node natively on my M1 machine. After installing NodeJS v15 through NVM I was able to compile my application for arm64(apple silicon) with no problem.

How could I switch back to installing NodeJs for Intel, so I can build my projects for both M1 and Intel on the same machine?

I tried reverting to a NodeJS version before v15, but that did not work when compiling.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://blog.arifsetyawan.com/notes-on-nodejs-in-apple-m1-via-nvm-e9cf3308ca86) would help?

Comment: Yes, the solution from the article works. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

> - Before installing the older node version with nvm we need to change zsh to work in x64 arch.
>
> ```
> arch -x86_64 zsh
> ```
>
> - Checking `node -p process.arch` then output x64 instead of arm64. means it able to run with rosetta 2.
> - After installing it, change zsh back to arm64
>
> ```
> arch -arm64 zsh
> ```
>
> - Rerun the lerna job and it's working normally. Each cpu monitored work averaging 40%, the temperature is normal (below 50 C), all job is marked as intel and the job done around 20 minutes (as expected).
>
> From [Notes on NodeJS in Apple M1 via NVM](https://blog.arifsetyawan.com/notes-on-nodejs-in-apple-m1-via-nvm-e9cf3308ca86)